# ASP.Net C# validating model based on MetadataType

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

My team is building ViewModels with model validation inside the MetadataType. My question is that I'm using a non-MVC project, can I use it to validate the model? If yes, can you please give an example?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetadata))]
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
 public class PersonMetadata
 {
        [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage="Name is required"), Required]
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Found this: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx

Comment: +1 Comment, helpful link, but finally what do you think using the Metadata or Fluent validator?

Comment: @M.Radwan I used FluentValidation now which seems cleaner and easier to use rather than MetaData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a good way to do things.  In general, using Metadata classes is a design smell.  I was recently turned on to [Fluent Validation for .NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/), which looks very promising, is pluggable for MVC but does not require MVC.

All that being said, it is doable:

```
        var person = new Person(); 
        var controllerSlashValidator = new FakeControllerValidator();
        ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary;
        bool isValid = controllerSlashValidator.Validate(person,out modelStateDictionary);
```

this code would need the `FakeControllerValidator` below

```
    public class FakeControllerValidator: Controller
    {
        public FakeControllerValidator()
        {
            this.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current),new RouteData()),this);
        }
        public bool Validate(object model, out ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary)
        {
            bool isValid = TryValidateModel(model);
            modelStateDictionary = ModelState;
            return isValid;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what a _design smell_ is?

Comment: @smartcavenman could you please provide reasons and reference why you consider using Metadata is a bad smell and how you see using fluent validation is better?

Comment: @M.Radwan, If you ask another question and post the link.  I will address it.  Extended conversation in comments is discouraged.

Comment: Why would you consider it a smell if the fluent validator basically does the same by associating metadata with the model.

Comment: @ChristopheGeers FluentValidation's metadata is completely decoupled from the model definition