# ASP.NET MVC3 using both Model and custom ValidationModel in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a View like this (unimportant stuff left out):

```
@model MyProject.Models.Accounts

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
```

Now, I have a separate Model I want to use for validation. Is it possible to use both my Model for data AND this validation Model in a View? Something like this:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Accounts
@validaitonmodel MyProject.Models.AccountValidationModel

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(validationmodel => validationmodel.Name)
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT***

By "Model" I mean the models that are automaticly generated by the .edmx (the Ado.net self-tracking entities)

By ValidationModel I mean a custom class like this:

```
public class AccountValidationModel
{
    [Required]
    public String Name {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Can you clarify a bit by what you mean "you have a separate model you want to use for validation." Can you give a more concrete example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the generally more acceptable practice is to either:

1. Add the attributes to your data model.
2. Bind your view to a separate ViewModel (in this case, your `AccountValidationModel`), and use a mapper tool (like [AutoMapper](http://google.ad.sgdoubleclick.net/pagead/nclk?sa=L&ai=1&fadurl=googleads.g.doubleclick.net&u=http%3A%2F%2Fautomapper.codeplex.com%2F&aclck=http%3A%2F%2Fcategoriesworld.net%2Fs.php%3Fquery%3Dautomapper)) to map the data between your two models.

Comment: i like #2. keeps your data and business layers out of the view.

Comment: Thanks, AutoMapper looks like the thing I need.

Answer (score 1):

May be the MetadataType attribute could help you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141.aspx

The Validation Model must implement all properties to validated, and MetadataTypeAttribute must be apply on the Model itself.

Quick sample from stackoverflow:
[ASP.Net C# validating model based on MetadataType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527411/asp-net-c-validating-model-based-on-metadatatype)

Or, like the guy, take a look for another way to validation with fluentvalidation (never  tried)
http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: But what if I have fields in my view like "ConfirmName" that need to be validated but are not present in my Model?

Comment: Yeah, this is why Domain Model is different of View Model. Like @Jerad Rose said: create a ViewModel and map properties with AutoMapper is probably the best and the simplest way. http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/10/27/12-asp.net-mvc-best-practices.aspx Also, you can easly set the ModelBinder Attribute on a ViewModel.