# Disable System.CompositionModel.DataAnnotation from generating db scema instead use it just for unobstrusive jquery validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I want to use System.CompositionModel.DataAnnotation for building Model but it should not affect database schema for example if I am using `Required` then it should not make that column as not nullable in Database. The reason I want to use Data annotation is for MVC 4 JQuery Unobstrusive validation.

As of Now I have applied validation by using

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BookingRequest.Email, new { data_val = "true", data_val_required = "Please provide Special Notes" })
```

I think this is not best practice or standard way to performing validation.

I want to change my model to something like this.

```
[Required]
public string Email { get; set; }
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
```

so that I don't need to pass html attribute while generating the html element in TextAreaFor but in database It should be nullable.

The reason why I am doing this is there is another service which is using same context but it does not provide the email value. And I don't want to change already running services.

I am using EntityTypeConfigurtaion(Fluent API) instead of DataAnnotation for configuring model.

Thanks in advance for your time to review my question.

Comment: the good idea is that you separate your database model and view models.... and write a converter to convert view model to database model

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clear from your explanation which EF approach you are using , here is my solution to DB first approach with entity framework :

add your validation attributes aka Dataanotation with same properties you are going to use in model-db

```
  public partial class XContent
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "UseLettersOnly", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

and create a partial class with same modal name and add metadata attribute to use above class

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(XContent))]
    public partial class YourModelClassName
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
```

so in an all

you have to add two classes one for mapping two classes 
and second which actually contains data-annotations

I hope that helps !!

Comment: It requires database schema changes which is not preferred as mentioned in question.

Comment: which ef approach you are using ?

Comment: :) , what i explained here works great with DB first not sure for code first , have a look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527411/asp-net-c-sharp-validating-model-based-on-metadatatype

Comment: You can see I am using fluent api. Doesn't it enough to indicate code first approach.